# Big prime factor of the prime number you feed to Diffie Hellman

Tags: diffie-hellman, prime-numbers, factoring

They say the security of Diffie-Hellman depends on the factorization of (N-1), where N is the big prime number you feed it.

More specifically, (N-1) itself has to have a big prime factor, such as (N-1)/2 also being prime.

My question isn't about why that's the case or how to tell if it has a big prime factor or not, I've seen those on here already.

My question is: **HOW BIG of a prime factor** does (N-1) need to have, in order for Diffie-Hellman to be considered secure, if N is let's say a 3000-bit prime? (N-1)/2 ? Divided by 4?  Or a prime factor that has twice as few bits as N would suffice? For example, if N is 3000-bit, then (N-1) having a 1500-bit prime factor is enough?

How big does the prime factor need to be for Diffie-Hellman to be considered secure enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: **HOW BIG** of a prime factor does (N-1) need to have, in order for Diffie-Hellman to be considered secure,

Background: if Diffie-Hellman, we have a generator $g$; the size of the subgroup generated by $g$ (that is, the number of values $g^x \bmod N$ can take on for various values of $x$) can be designated by $q$.  That is the "large prime factor of $N-1$" (and we usually select $g$ such that $q$ is prime; if you select a subgroup that isn't of prime size, then we can assume $q$ is the largest prime factor).

With that background in place, one way to attack Diffie-Hellman is to take one of the keyshares $g^x \bmod N$ and try to recover $x$ using a generic group attack (such as Baby-Step-Giant-Step); if we recover $x$, it becomes simple to recover the shared secret.  Now, it can be shown that such a generic group attack (and there are several known) always takes $\Omega( \sqrt{q} )$ steps [1].  In addition, we know algorithms for which the implied constant in $\Omega( \sqrt{q} )$ isn't that far from 1.

Because of this, if we have a security level $\lambda$, that is, we want to ensure that it takes at least $2^\lambda$ operations to break it, we need to ensure that $\sqrt{q} \ge 2^\lambda$, that is, $q \ge 2^{2 \lambda}$.  Or, in other words, the prime factor needs to have a bit length (at least) twice as long as the security level we hope to achieve.  For example, if we are aiming at a 128 bit security level, this means that the prime factor needs to be at least 256 bits long.

Of course, there are other attacks which depend on the size of $N$; those attacks give other constraints on the size of $N$.

[1]: This $\Omega$ notation is just like the more common $O$ notation, except that it gives a lower bound, not an upper one; that is, for the attack to succeed with a given probability (given a random instance) always takes at least $M \sqrt{q}$ operations, for some constant $M$.

Comment: So G is the generator (which is usually a very small prime, right?) and M is the modulus, which is a very big prime, these are both public. Alice and Bob pick A and B, both randomly chosen between 1 and M and then send to each other (G^A) mod M and (G^B) mod M, respectively. M is the big prime that needs to have a big prime factor for the security of DH to work, right? if M is a 3000-bit prime, how big of a prime factor would it need to have?

Comment: @KevinStefanov: Actually, $G$ needs not be either small or prime; what is crucial is that it generates your large prime subgroup (and if you pick a $q \lll N-1$, then $g$ will almost never be small).  If $M$ is a 3000-bit prime, which would take circa $2^{128}$ operations to break using NFS, then the prime group should be at least 256 bits (any smaller would actively reduce the security; larger wouldn't directly help security, but may be useful for other reasons).

Comment: @KevinStefanov: and, if you are looking at using a well-vetted DH group, you could do worse than using one of the groups found in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3526/

Comment: So what you're saying is that if M is a 3000-bit prime, then it needs to have a 256-bit prime factor for DH to be considered secure?

Comment: @KevinStefanov: *at least* 256 bits to have circa 128 bits of security.  Again, nothing wrong with going larger (there's a lot to be said for picking $N$ such that $(N-1)/2$ is prime)

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer! What would you recommend for checking if a 3000-bit N has a prime factor of at least 256 bits? Do I just check if N divides by a few random 256-bit numbers, then a few random 257-bit numbers and so on? Because checking every single 256-bit number, every single 257-bit number and so on sounds like way too long.

Comment: @KevinStefanov: other way around; you pick your 256 bit $q$ and then look for a 3000 bit prime of the form $kq+1$; that's your $N$

Comment: Thank you!!! You're awesome!

Comment: @KevinStefanov: another example is the [2048-bit MODP group with 256-bit prime order subgroup of RFC 5114](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5114.html#section-2.3). It's believed to be comparably secure to the [2048-bit MODP group of RFC 3526](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3526#section-3).